# How can i open my .chm to be merged into another .chm into a new window?

Tags: merge, chm, html-help, robohelp

Using Robohelp if it matters.  How can i get the path at runtime of my help file in HtmlHelp?  I have a .chm that is merged (but not by me, by the main application).  How can i get the slave .chm to open in its own window when its entry in the TOC is clicked?
This worked using a "hidden" file with some javascript, but doesn't work after the merge:

```
<a href="Hidden.htm">Click For SlaveB.chm through hidden</a>
```

This is in the "hidden" htm file:

```
<object
      classid="clsid:ADB880A6-D8FF-11CF-9377-00AA003B7A11"
      id="window_opener"  type="application/x-oleobject">
      <param  name="Command"  value="Shortcut" />
      <param  name="Font"  value="Microsoft Sans Serif,8,0,," />
      <param  name="Item1"  value=",hh.exe,./SlaveB.chm::/MyTopic.htm"/>
    </object>

    <!--Metadata type="DesignerControl" endspan-->
     <script type="text/javascript">window_opener.hhclick();
    history.back();</script>
```

This worked but doesn't open my .chm in a new window:

```
<p><a href="SlaveB.chm::/MyTopic.htm">Click For MyTopic.htm in same window</a></p>
```

It also worked if i use a hard coded absolute path to the .chm with a topic.  I simply want to find the path the current .chm is working from and open a.chm (which is in the same directory) in a new window.  This can be a simple .chm that is merged that only provides the link/open of the other .chm (the one i want to open in a new window).  For example, SlaveA.chm IS merged into the main app's Master .chm (i don't have access to edit this one), but SlaveA simply exists for a TOC entry in Master that links/opens my SlaveB.chm in a completely new window (slave B is not merged at all)

Comment: I also used the javascript method with window_opener to open absolute path, which worked.  problem is, i won't know the drive letter etc when the user installs all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following javascript to get the location, remove the end and place my slave .chm file on the end, then open it in a new window:

```
<button onclick="showExternalHelp()">Show Help</button> 

<script type="text/javascript">function showExternalHelp()
{
var location = window.location.pathname;
var splitter = "\\";
var lastIndex = location.lastIndexOf(splitter);

location = location.substring(0, lastIndex);
location = location + "\\External.chm";

window.showHelp(location);

}</script>
```

Comment: Doing this allowed the index and seach to work, since it wouldn't when the 3rd party app merged my help into its own, without control by me.